# Where to store subdomain assets?

Tags: php, laravel

Okay, so when I first started I began storing my assets in `document_root/resources/assets\js\something.js`

Now I learn that index shouldn't be outside of the `public` folder and should be inside the public folder to avoid access to other folders. This means I can't use the old location, and someone told me I should store them in `/public/assets/js/something.js` instead.

So my question is, what's the point in `/resources/assets` ? And how do you store sub domain assets? Under another folder?

Answer (score 0):

The point of resources/assets is to contain your source assets (js, img, css, etc...).
You could then compile / transpile / copy / (choose what you want to do) them onto the public/assets folter to be accessible from the internet.

The resources folder could for example look like this :

```
/resources
    /assets
       /fonts
       /img
       /scss (contains files that cannot be understood by the web browser)
       /ts (same here)
```

While your public folder :

```
/public
    /assets
       /fonts
       /img
       /css (contains css files compiled from your scss files)
       /js (contains javascript files transpiled from typescript)
```

This is where [Laravel mix](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mix) comes.